# R: How to perform lsa() with parallel processing format

Tags: r, parallel-processing, text-analysis, lsa

I am trying to do some text analytic on tweets, and trying to use LSA() for DR.
However, seems like calculating lsa space is EXTREMELY memory intensive. I can only process up to 2.3k tweets or my computer will die.

As I researched through online resources for parallel processing, I learned that, even though my computer is 4 core, i'll only use 1 of them because that's the default setting in R.
I've also read [this post here](http://gforge.se/2015/02/how-to-go-parallel-in-r-basics-tips/#The_parallel_package) that is extremely helpful, but seems like that parallel processing can only be done:

1. on functions that can be used in apply() families
2. to replace for loops

I am trying to use parallel processing for lsa().
Here's my one line code:

```
lsa.train = lsa(tdm.train, dimcalc_share())
```

where the **tdm.train** is a TermDocumentMatrix with terms as rows and documents as columns.

#### my question is:

how can i change this line of code of lsa() so that it'll process in parallel format instead of sequential format? such that it'll use n cores instead of 1 core only, where n is number of cores defined by the user (me).